# Would you say 当动词 or 是动词?

Tags: grammar

I am back to the classic 当 vs。 是。 I've heard some people say “这个词也可以是动词” however could  I also say "这个词 也可以当动词“  － if so, which sounds more common/colloquial?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`当` here means `act as; be regarded as; be considered as`.

`是` is simply `to be`.

Both words are common and can be used colloquially. In formal/academic context, I'd replace `当` with `作` or `当做`.

If the word is not verb but can be used as a verb, you should say 当, e.g.

> 在古汉语里，很多形容词都可以**当**动词。

If the word is a verb, you should say 是, e.g.

> 服务这个词既是名词，又**是**动词。

Comment: So 当 is used when referring to the non-general usage of the word?

Comment: @Stephen Not exactly but I'm lack of a better way to describe it. To raise another example, check out this sentence: 'In English, the present participle for a verb _can be used_ as a noun or an adjective'. '英语中动词的现在分词形式一般可当名词或形容词'. Instead of saying 'swimming是名词', we'd say 'swimming是swim的现在分词形式当做名词'.

Comment: like "acting as" - no that definitely makes sense